# Different inheritance types in the same schema

Tags: inheritance, symfony1, doctrine, concrete-inheritance, column-aggregation

I'm using Doctrine 1.2 on a symfony project,
and I'm considering mixing concrete and column aggregation inheritance types in my schema:
column aggregation lets me query in a parent table and get both parent and child records, while concrete inheritance lets me get a cleaner schema.
Plus, the mix will be in the same inheritance chain.
How would I write the schema file? Like the following?

```
A:

B:
  inheritance:
    extends: A
    type: concrete

C:
  inheritance:
    extends: B
    type: column_aggregation
    keyField:         type
    keyValue:         1
```

Or like this perhaps:

```
A:

B:
  inheritance:
    extends: A
    type: concrete

C:
  inheritance:
    extends: B
    type: concrete
D:
  inheritance:
    extends: C
    type: column_aggregation
    keyField:         type
    keyValue:         1


E:
  inheritance:
    extends: C
    type: column_aggregation
    keyField:         type
    keyValue:         2
```

Are there any dangers/caveats ?

Comment: Looks like no one else has experience to share. I'd be interested to know how this went though - my initial thought was that it'd not work well.

Comment: @benlumley Well, we've tried it, and we are testing, and it seems to work pretty well for the moment. I'll edit my post and add a comment if we encounter some problems though. We tried with the second version of the schema.

Comment: @greg0ire: BEWARE relations when concrete inheritance is involved :-) MAke sure you dont define them on the base table. Ive never mixed and matched to any extent either so ill be itnerested to hear of any issue you come across...

Comment: @prodigitalson : could you elaborate? Why exactly is inherinting the relation dangerous? Because of the foreign aliases. I'll post here any issue I come across (including this one if it is one).

Comment: @greg0ire: Because with concrete inheritence the base table (`A`) is created but not used. If you have foreign keys that point to `A` the key check will fail because the data is actually stored in `B`. As long as you keep your relations on the aggregation tables you should be ok though. But in some some cases that kind of defeats the purpose of having `A` to begin with.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Thank you for this clarification. We were aware that we could not retrieve all objects of a sub-type from the parent type table with concrete inheritance, but we hadn't thought about this relation problem. Luckily, we have no relations on the parent table, so everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you **avoid** circular inheritance or diamond shaped inheritance you would be fine and can use this

A **circular** inheritance (obviously looks as follows

> Class A Extends B
>   Class B Extends A

OR

> CLASS A EXTENDS C
>
> CLASS B EXTENDS A
>
> CLASS C EXTENDS A

A **Diamond** Shaped inheritance is a bit more round about. It happens when the following type of condition happens

> CLASS A
>
> CLASS B EXTENDS A
>
> CLASS C EXTENDS A
>
> CLASS D EXTENDS B,C

Comment: Are you saying multiple inheritance is possible with doctrine? Since it is not with php, I doubt it... +1 for the vocabulary though

Comment: All i am trying to say is as long as these constrains are not there. We can safely do inheritance.